# Можно ли управлять веб-сайтом через консольное приложение?

Tags: c#, .net

Можно ли управлять веб-сайтом через консольное приложение? Например, я хочу удалить кэш или куки, могу ли я это сделать написав пару строчек кода в .NET. Или, как мне, допустим, получить адресную строку и записать ее в переменную или же получить любой DOM элемент. Если это возможно, то прошу не жалейте времени и опишите, хотя бы примерно, как это выглядит, спасибо.

Comment: Всё перечисленное, очевидно, относится к браузеру, а не к веб-сайту. В первую очередь выясняйте, существует ли какой-нибудь API для управления браузером, который вы используете, и имеет ли он требуемые вами возможности

Answer (score 0):

Надеюсь, наведёт на нужные мысли:

[**CURL**](https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/CURL) - Свободная, кроссплатформенная служебная программа командной строки, позволяющая взаимодействовать с множеством различных серверов по множеству различных протоколов с синтаксисом URL.

[**PhantomJS**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/PhantomJS) - браузер на основе WebKit без графического интерфейса. Работает под управлением JavaScript. Поддерживает различные стандарты и технологии: DOM, CSS, JSON, Canvas и SVG.

[**Firefox headless mode**](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/Firefox/Headless_mode) - опция, позволяющая запускать браузер **Firefox** без графического интерфейса. Управление в командной строке и с помощью JavaScript.

[**Headless Chromium**](https://chromium.googlesource.com/chromium/src/+/lkgr/headless/README.md) - тоже опция, аналогично **Firefox**. Из описания: *"отличный инструмент для автоматизированного тестирования и серверных сред, где вам не нужна видимая оболочка пользовательского интерфейса. Например, может потребоваться выполнить некоторые тесты для реальной веб-страницы, создать PDF-файл или просто проверить, как браузер отображает URL-адрес."*